# How to fix this error? Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

in viewModel:

```
enum ListScreenState { initial, loading, loaded, error }
class ServiceDetailsViewModelProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ListScreenState state = ListScreenState.initial;
  late String errorMessage;
  late ApiResult apiResult;
  bool _isFavorited = false; // Initial value
  bool get isFavorited => _isFavorited;
  Future<void> checkiffavorite(int id) async {
    setState(ListScreenState.loading);
    notifyListeners();
    final apiResult = await DioServiceProvider().checkiffavorite(id);
    if (!apiResult.hasError) {
      setState(ListScreenState.loaded);
      if (apiResult.data['status'] == 'yes') {
        _isFavorited = true;
      } else if (apiResult.data['status'] == 'no') {
        _isFavorited = false;
      }
    } else {
      errorMessage = apiResult.failure.message;
      notifyListeners();
      setState(ListScreenState.error);
    }
  }
  setState(state) {
    this.state = state;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

in view :
i'm calling this function in my screen as one of children of stack

```
StatelessWidget checkFavoriteMethod(BuildContext context, service) {
    final viewModel = Provider.of<ServiceDetailsViewModelProvider>(context);
    if (viewModel.state == ListScreenState.initial) {
      viewModel.checkiffavorite(service.id);
      return Container();
    } else if (viewModel.state == ListScreenState.loading) {
      return Container();
    } else if (viewModel.state == ListScreenState.error) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      return InkWell(
        highlightColor: ColorManager.transparent, // Disable focus color
        splashColor: ColorManager.transparent,
        onTap: () {
          viewModel.editFavorite(service.id);
        },
        child: viewModel.isFavorited
            ? Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: ColorManager.primary,
                size: AppSize.s30,
              )
            : const Icon(
                Icons.star_border_outlined,
                size: AppSize.s30,
              ),
      );
    }
  }
```

when run app in emulator, return this error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for
ServiceDetailsViewModelProvider:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This _InheritedProviderScope<ServiceDetailsViewModelProvider?> widget cannot be marked as needing
to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked
as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building.
This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a
dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during
this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  _InheritedProviderScope<ServiceDetailsViewModelProvider?>
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  ServiceDetailScreen.
...............
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line

```
viewModel.checkiffavorite(service.id);
```

in `checkFavoriteMethod` because in this method you're calling `setState`, and this throws an exception because you're basically altering the state of the widget when the widget itself hasn't been built yet, and Flutter does not allow this (probably because of risk of infinite loops).  Simply put, you can't invoke `setState` in `build` method of a `StatefulWidget`.

If you need some things defined before a widget is built, you could probably override `initState`: in that method you can initialize some variable that might be needed during the building of the widget itself.

EDIT:

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeData();
  }

  void _initializeData() {
    _counter = 42;
    print('Initialized counter in initState');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Counter: $_counter'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(example taken from [here](https://www.scaler.com/topics/initstate-flutter/))

The method `initState` is used when you need a default state for a widget, but the data needed to do this isn't readily available: since you can't call `setState` at build time, it allows you to define some values for your state without having to call `setState`. The link provides more complex examples.

Comment: I'm using stateLessWidget not StatefulWidget,can you give me example for your proposition?

Comment: Added something to the answer

Comment: thanks, yes i get it , but i want use provider with statelessWidget